Detecting Hole Creation in a Cellular Automaton
I'm working on a cellular automaton related to Diffusion-Limited aggregation where the simulation runs on a grid. Each cell is either EMPTY or FULL.
Once a cell transitions from EMPTY to FULL (according to the CA rules), it remains FULL permanently. This results in a connected cluster of FULL cells, potentially forming holes — connected clusters of EMPTY cells completely surrounded by FULL cells.
What I want is to find all currently EMPTY cells, such that if they were to transition from EMPTY to FULL a new hole would be formed in the central structure.
Here's an example picture:

Where:

Black = FULL
White = EMPTY
Red = Cells that if filled, would create a new hole

Currently, I brute-force the solution by iterating through each EMPTY cell, filling it temporarily, and recalculating the number of EMPTY connected components and check if it increased. This is very slow on larger grids (e.g. 1000 x 1000).
What I might be looking for then, is a data structure that allows me to calculate the initial connectivities once and quickly add/remove cells and re-calculates connectivities quickly as well. But I might be going into to a totally wrong direction in general, so I am open to ideas.

Find all articulation points, by computing the biconnected components of the graph of empty cells.  This gives a linear-time algorithm that finds all such cells at once.

Thanks! I'll test it when I get back to the problem but this seems like exactly what I am looking for. Marking as the solution!
